# HTML select change event not called when selecting value of html select using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below code I am binding the change event to a HTML select and then trying to set its selected value. However, my change event is not called when I select the value of the HTML select via jQuery with the following code:

```
row.find(".js-sAttribute").change(function ()
{
    alert('1');
});

//**the following should trigger change event binded in the above code**
row.find(".js-sAttribute").each(function() { this.selected = (this.text == sAttEnum.ProductID); });
```

Please advise.

Comment: I see conflicting code.  Can you clean up your question a bit to be more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you need to do is call change() with no arguments after you change the selection manually.  Otherwise, it won't actually trigger the change event...

```
row.find(".js-sAttribute").each(function() { 
   this.selected = (this.text == sAttEnum.ProductID);
   $(this).change(); 
});
```